# How can I make the URL search engine friendly?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to cahange mysite.com/profile.php into mysite.com/profile

I wrote the htacess file as

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^profile/?$ profile.php [NC,L]
```

and placed in root directory. It doesn't work. I use the apache server. What is wrong with my program?

Comment: If you're going to take the time to ask for help, please edit your question for spelling, grammar, and punctuation.

Comment: @philfreo: Not everyone is a native English speaker. The question is more than clear enough to be understood.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

That way you dont have to do it for each individual URL.

[credit](http://newmediarts.blogspot.com/2007/01/hide-file-extensions-in-urls-with.html)

Comment: I need some more explanation.because I am newbie to URL rewriting.What does !-d and -f indicates

Comment: !-d means "if it's not a directory"

-f means "if it's a regular file"

So... if the requested filename isn't a directory, but the same path with .php is appended, send the PHP file.

Comment: BTW, got that from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html as the official reference docs. You should also check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/ for more rewrite-foo.

Comment: You don’t need to escape the dot in `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` since that’s not a regular expression.