# Technique to create user friendly URLs

Tags: php, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create friendly URL in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php)

I have read a lot of content on Google about turning

`profile.php?id=24` into something more user friendly.

How would I go about redirecting a link like

```
www.site.com/profile/username
```

to

```
profile.php?id=userid (find from username)
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create friendly URL in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php) and [How can I make the URL search engine friendly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653520/how-can-i-make-the-url-search-engine-friendly) and [tons of others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+user+friendly+url&submit=search). Please use the search before you ask a question.

Comment: Actually the initial link is generally more like `www.site.com/profile/userid/username`. The username is just there for convenience and isn't used in the URL translation. Look at how SO works for example.

Comment: You could've done some research. The answer to this question is found 5.3 million times on Google already

Comment: I always trust the answers of users on this website more than random articles found on Google.

Comment: @Cicada, I understand what you mean about the userid and username being together. Makes a lot of sense rather than running a query to find the id from the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) RewriteEngine. An example .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/profile/username/([\d]+)$ profile.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [apache rewrite rules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Apache will internally rewrite a URL like `/profile/username` to `profile.php?username=username`.

Example: (place this in a .htaccess in the same directory than profile.php)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/profile/(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1
```

If you profile.php script doesn't accept a `username` parameter, you could also include the user id in the user friendly url:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/profile/(.*)-(\d+)$ profile.php?id=$2
```

This will rewrite urls like `/profile/username-id` to `profile.php?id=id`

See apahe [mod_rewrite documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is done by creating a RewriteRule in a .htaccess file, of by defining rules in httpd.conf. 
This works on Apache. I'm, not sure how to do this on other servers.

Answer (score 0):

When your users sign up, use a PHP or CGI script to make a file called "Username.txt" and store it in a folder called Profiles (as you have it). And inside the text file, make it generate the number (counting up or hashed?) Or use a rewrite service in Google or Apache.